# Got error "passwords do not match" using passwd in docker

Tags: linux, docker, passwd

I wanna create a user had random password for FTP in Docker. The section of Dockerfile like below:

```
RUN useradd web
RUN export ftppass=`cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`
RUN echo -e "$ftppass\n$ftppass" | passwd web
```

But I got an error in last line:

```
New password: Retype new password: Sorry, passwords do not match.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Why the passwords do not match even I using a same variable?

---

update:

I found the output of `echo -e "$ftppass\n$ftppass"` is:

```
Step 9/15 : RUN echo -e "$ftppass\n$ftppass"
 ---> Running in ddd97df41d85
-e

Removing intermediate container ddd97df41d85
 ---> a64b606ea898
Step 10/15 : ...
```

Why it's not works for `echo -e` and where are my $ftppass?

---

Resolved, the new section of Dockerfile is:

```
RUN useradd web
RUN cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid > /etc/vsftp-password
RUN echo "web:"`cat /etc/vsftp-password` | chpasswd
RUN echo "ftp info web:"`cat /etc/vsftp-password`
```

Thanks anyone and happy new year~

Comment: Did you run the echo command without the pipe to test what it echoes? Underscores and a backslash may make it hard for the shell to identify where the variable name ends without curly braces delimiting. I am only guessing no shell at hand and happy New Year in mind.

Comment: You should use `pnintf` with a format string instead, like `printf '%s\n' "$ftppass" "$ftppass"`. But I second the answer by Roland; don't use `passwd` in scripts.

Comment: Unix/Linux questions should be programming related. I suggest to visit https://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `passwd` in a creative way, you should rather look at its [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/passwd.1.html), which mentions `chpasswd` in the See Also section.

The `passwd` command is meant for interactive use, and it doesn't read its input like most other programs, since the input is not echoed to the screen.

Comment: Actually `useradd` lets you specify a password directly.